# Does changing debit card protect me from a scammer?

Tags: united-kingdom, scams

In case I have given out my CVV on the back of my debit card to a call deal that I got (so I did not call the dealer), and in case I change my current debit card worried about a scam, can the dealer still take money from me?

Comment: You should contact your bank and let them know the card is compromised. There may be additional steps they can take in those cases.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they can take money from you for as long as you have your current card.

If you're worried, you should call your bank and ask them to freeze your card straight away, and then they'll send out a new one which will have a new debit card number and CV2.

Answer (score 2):

Well the old card should be blocked and the new one should have a new number, so I cannot immediately see how they could.